# How can I use an newer package to satisfy an older dependency?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04, dependencies

I want to use Bombono to author some DVDs, but unlike 16.04 and 18.04, 20.04 doesn't have this package in the repositories. So I downloaded the relevant packages from the 18.04 repos and tried to install them. A regular, non-forced install attempt will be rejected due to unmet dependencies, even though every missing dependency exists in a newer form in 20.04. Using `dpkg -i --force-install` breaks apt until I remove Bombono. How can I tell `dpkg` or `apt` to use these new packages to satisfy the older dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will be disappointing. `.deb` installation packages are recreated for each specific distribution to match dependencies available on the current version.  A specific `.deb` file is designed to connect to specific dependencies. Thus, by design, you cannot have an older `.deb` use newer dependencies.

Even if you unpack the `.deb` with the aim to repackage it, the binary code of the application may not work with the current versions of the dependencies, and there is no way you can change/edit these binaries.

For older software that is no longer supported, and that does not anymore run on newer versions, you may have no other option than to attempt recompiling the code on your current system. That may require adapting the program code as well.

Comment: This is correct. I tried using `equivs`, and after a lot of time making dummies, I got errors from missing .so files (IME linking the old files to the new files rarely works without also hand-editing the old .so files, so I didn't even try because that's always a nightmare) and building from source requires resolving problems with both the build scripts and the code itself. I'm making progress towards something that builds, but if it doesn't work I'll have to use an older version of Ubuntu because I just lack the knowledge to mess with the build scrips and I lack the time to work on the code.